# Open Mappinig Theorem doubts on Brezis's Book

Tags: functional-analysis

In famous book of Brezi's book of Functional Analysis that can be found [here](http://www-dimat.unipv.it/giulio/linkedmaterial/af/Brezis.pdf). I have some doubts on the also famous open mapping theorem in his first step on page 36, where he wants to prove that if $T$ is a linear surjective operator from $E$ onto $F$ two Banach Spaces, then there exists a constant $c$ such that

$$ B(0,2c) \subset \overline{T(B(0,1))} $$

1º) He begins asserting that if $X_n = n \overline{T(B(0,1)}$ since $T$ is surjective then $ \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n = F$ This is not obvious for me. I know the following

\begin{equation}
 E = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} B(0,n) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{B(0,n)}
\end{equation} 
Then,
\begin{equation}
F = T(E) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{B(0,n)}.
\end{equation}

2º) He says something like $y_0 \in \overline{T(B(0,1)}$ then by symmetry $-y_0 \in \overline{T(B(0,1)}$ ? Maybe by the context.

3º) Finally he says,  since $\overline{T(B(0,1)}$ is convex, we have
\begin{equation}
\overline{T(B(0,1)} + \overline{T(B(0,1)} = 2\overline{T(B(0,1)}?
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take the closures only at the end: $$F = T(E) = T\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nB(0,1)\right) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty T(nB(0,1)) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty nT(B(0,1)) \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty n\overline{T(B(0,1))}.$$
2. $T$ is linear, $B(0,1)$ is balanced, hence $T(B(0,1))$ is balanced, hence $\overline{T(B(0,1))}$ is balanced. So $y_0 \in \overline{T(B(0,1))} \iff -y_0 \in \overline{T(B(0,1))}$.
3. For all convex $A$ we have $A+A = 2A$, since $a_1 + a_2 = 2\left(\frac{1}{2} a_1 + \frac{1}{2} a_2\right)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I only don't undertand  what do you mean by "balanced"?

Comment: Balanced is equilibrée; a set $A$ is balanced if for every $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ for real vector spaces) with $\lvert \lambda\rvert \leqslant 1$ you have $\lambda \cdot A \subset A$. Some people write "disked" or "circled", iirc.

Comment: I understand now thank you.